# Tensorflow import error (Windows10) (python3.5.3) (tensorflow-gpu #243 nightly binary)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

### Environment:

Windows10

Python 3.5.3 64bit

CUDA Toolkit 8.0

cuDNN v5.1(extracted to Toolkit8.0 files)

Visual Studio Community 2015

Nightly binary[#243](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/M=windows-gpu,PY=35/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/cmake_build/tf_python/dist/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl) Tensorflow GPU version (`pip install tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`)

---

**The package has not been installed correctly, and the file `_pywrap_tensorflow.pyd` is not present in the `C:\...\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python`**

### After I got nearly the same error as [#5949](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949), I tried mrry's tensorflow_self_check.py.

The output is:

ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.

- Python version is 3.5.
- TensorFlow is installed at: C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow
- All required DLLs are present. Please open an issue on the
  TensorFlow GitHub page: github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

---

### However, I can import the tensorflow successfully if I use the below version:

`pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

So, what's wrong the tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1 version?

I really hope someone can help me solve it completely. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using an environment manager? If so can you try in a fresh environment `pip install tensorflow-gpu` please.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Anaconda for the windows, if you want to try tensorflow. The number of issues is very less.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

But if you really want to work without anaconda.

- Check your path to Cuda, Cudnn and python.
- Ensure that cudnn is v5.1
- TensorFlow 1.3 or later requires cuDNN 6.
- Installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587) (x64 version) can fix it.

Do let me know about after trying above steps.